# Process many EDI files through single MFX

Tags: map-force

I've created a mapping in MapForce 2013 and exported the MFX file. Now, I need to be able to run the mapping using MapForce Server. The problem is, I need to specify both the input EDI file and the output file. As far as I can tell, the usage pattern is to run the mapping with MapForce server using the input/output configuration in the MFX itself, not passed in on the command line.

I suppose I could change the input/output to some standard file name and then just write the input file to that path before performing the mapping, and then grab the output from the standard output file path when the mapping is complete.

But I'd prefer to be able to do something like:

```
MapForceServer run -in=MyInputFile.txt -out=MyOutputFile.xml MyMapping.mfx > MyLogFile.txt
```

Is something like this possible? Perhaps using parameters within the mapping?

Answer (score 0):

There are two options that I've come across in dealing with a similar situation.

Option 1- If you set the input XML file to *.xml in the component settings, mapforceserver.exe will automatically process all txt in the directory assuming your source is xml (this should work for text just the same). Similar to the example below you can set a cleanup routine to move the files into another folder after processing.

Note: It looks in the folder where the schema file is located.

Option 2 - Since your output is XML you can use Altova's raptorxml (rack up another license charge).  Now you can generate code in XSLT 2.0 and use a batch file to automatically execute, something like this.

```
::@echo off
for %%f IN (*.xml) DO (RaptorXML xslt --xslt-version=2 --input="%%f" --output="out/%%f" %* "mymapping.xslt"

if NOT errorlevel 1 move "%%f" processed 
if errorlevel 1 move "%%f" error)
sleep 15
mymapping.bat
```

I tossed in a sleep command to loop the batch for rechecking every 15 seconds.  Unfortunately this does not work if your output target is a database.

Comment: One last note one this... many miles of mapforce behind me now.  To answer the original question more directly,  just use a * instead of a file name for the source and it the mfx will process everything in the folder.